# Where is the location of the System class in Java?

Tags: java

Actually we are getting the values from `System` class by using the `System.getProperty("keyValue")` method. Is this values varied from one application to another application. I mean, is the `System` class varied from one application to another application?

What is the location of the `System` class?

Comment: Please don't ask questions that can be answered by your own self through "experimentations" such as "what will happen if I do this instead of that". Also google before asking

Comment: Define 'location of the System class'. It is in a fixed package, `java.lang`, but that doesn't sound like what you are asking about. Nothing sounds like what you are asking about, actually. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

The System class is in `java.lang`. All of `java.lang` is automatically imported.

You can verify this for yourself by looking here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Basically, you implicitly have

```
import java.lang.*;
```

At the top of every class.

In terms of how the System class varies, it varies based on a couple of factors:

1. Java version: With different Java versions, you might have different properties enabled.
2. Runtime Environment: If you're running on a different OS, for example, you'll have different file separators, default paths, etc. This will make it change. Even between OS versions or different architectures, this will change.

If you decide to change variables in the System class, those variables are *temporary* changes. Those are stored in memory, and will be dumped if the application is closed and will be inaccessible to other Java environments.

Comment: Thanks. We can set userdefined properties by using setProperty() method. Are this values will be will be available for every application or to that particular application?. I mean, are these values available only in the application where we set?

Comment: Just that application. They're stored in memory in that specific JVM, and anything within that JVM will have access to those properties, but any concurrent JVMs or future JVMs will keep the default set of properties (unless you otherwise change them)

Answer (score 0):

It is in `java.lang` package. Fully qualified name `java.lang.System`. And I think this doesn't change as it is a part of Core Java SE classes.

Answer (score 0):

System Class is located under the  default package of java `java.lang.Sytem`

Does not change aat any cost , It's  an default API in java

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

We no need to import the `java.lang.*` package it will imported automatically